# Mysql getting wrong information from information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

Writing in Linux/Lucee and Coldfusion/Mysql.  I have several databases in my system, with quite a few tables overlapping.  I have a program which would add a field to a given table, say Activity, in each database.  Of course I don't want to alter a non-existent table, so I am checking to make sure the table is there.

The simplest way would be to go to the database and use "show tables like 'Activity'".  To do that in ColdFusion I used the datasource that belongs to that database.  However, when I tried that, I got zero tables even when the table is present.

```
<cfquery name = 'tbl' datasource = '#thedatasource#'>
  show tables like 'Activity'
</cfquery>
```

The record count for this query is zero.  Then I tried using the information schema and got better results with this test program:

```
 <cfquery name = 'dblist' datasource = 'Moxart'>
    select MoxcoId from Moxco
 </cfquery>

 <cfloop query = 'dblist'> 
 <cfoutput> 
    <cfquery name = 'tbl' datasource = 'Moxart'>
       select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables
       where table_schema = '#MoxcoId#' AND table_name = 'Activity'
    </cfquery>
    <cfdump var = '#tbl#'>
 </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

This gave exactly the right answer.  However, when I put the same code into the real program, it keeps returning zero records.  The real program is rather long, however most of the beginning consists of picking up info from the previous form .  From the line

```
 <cfquery name = 'dblist' datasource = 'Moxart'>
```

the only difference is the addition of this section because #MoxcoId# is not always the schema name.  The variable #mmox# is in this case blank, so doesn't add anything.

```
<cfif #MoxcoId# EQ 'Moxart'>
         <cfset pref = '#mmox#Moxware'>
      <cfelse>
          <cfset pref = '#mmox##MoxcoId#'>
      </cfif>
```

When I do a dump on the query 'tbl' it shows that zero records were retrieved, even though the code appears to be exactly correct.

[image]

I am baffled.  There must be something wrong in my code, but I just can't see it. If anyone can suggest something I would appreciate it.

Comment: Note you'll only see tables in the information_schema to which the database user has permissions on.

Comment: true, but the test program worked, so the permissions must be okay.

Comment: This is solved.  Although it is not showing in the <cfdump, apparently my prefix was picking up an extra space.  Using Trim fixed it.